# Unit testing in Python on a function that doesn't have a return value? Is including test-specific code in a function bad practice?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I am writing a mock-up Auction site in Django as part of my self-learning to code. I'm at the point where I'm learning to write tests for my software but I've encountered the problem where a number of my functions used for the web app do not normally return a value. In this one example, I included a boolean parameter for a function that checks whether it is being tested or not. If the parameter is true, it executes a block of code that then does return value that I can then assert with unittest.

This is the function:

```
def cleantags(testing=False) -> None:
    """Executed on listing update, delete, or accept.
    Purges tags in 'Category' that are no longer used"""
    unused_tags = Category.objects.filter(Q(listing__isnull=True) | Q(listing__sold=True))
    for _tag in unused_tags:
        _tag.delete()

    if testing:
        deleted_tags = []
        for _tag in unused_tags:
            deleted_tags.append(_tag.__str__())
        return deleted_tags
```

This is the unittest:

```
def test_tag_deleted(self):
        """Checking that cleantags() will purge tags in Catergories
        that don't belong to a listing or to one that has sold."""
        # ['Lions','Tigers','Bears','Foo','Bar']
        tag_objs = self.generate_tags()
        self.listing1.tags.add(tag_objs[0])
        self.listing1.tags.add(tag_objs[1])

        self.listing2.tags.add(tag_objs[2])
        self.listing2.sold = True
              
        del_tags = listmng.cleantags(True)
        self.assertListEqual(del_tags, ['Foo','Bar'])
```

I guess my main question is if this is considered bad coding practice, and if so is there a better way to ensure that functions like "cleantags()" work as intended?

Comment: The right way to test this method would be to set up a fresh database with a predefined set of `Category` objects, some of which have listings and some don't.  Then call the function, and then inspect the database afterwards to make sure there are no remaining `Category` objects without listings.

Comment: You have discovered the danger of tacking testing onto an already designed system.  If it wasn't designed for testability in the first place, it's going to be unreasonably difficult.  One of the big benefits of functional programming is that it's inherently testable,  A function that takes all its input as parameters and not side-loaded state, and produces all its output as return values, is almost trivial to test.